# str_replace Increment variable value in each record found

Tags: php

I have an html string in which I have to paint an html code, but I would be interested if a variable included in the str_replace increases its value when I find some html in the html.

```
$codigoU = 1000;

$info = str_replace(array('</p><div', '</div></div>'),array('<div><br class="'.$codigoU.'"><input type="button"class=="'.$codigoU.'"></div><input type="text" class="tex" value="" placeholder="Eti"></div><br class="'.$codigoU.'"><br class="'.$codigoU.'">', '</div></div></div></div>'),$info);
```

Here is my code, would there be a way to call a function when the str_replace method encounters a match that causes the $ variable code to be incremented by its value?

It would look something like this:

```
$codigoU ++;
```

If there is another way to do it I have not found it on the net, I would need to increase that variable and I do not know how I could do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a callback to `str_replace()` for "encountering a match", but you *can* [count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) before replacing those occurrences.  Something like:

```
$codigoU += substr_count($your_substring, $your_string);
```

Since you're using arrays, you may need to do this in a loop.  Something like:

```
$substrings = array('</p><div', '</div></div>');
foreach ($substrings as $substring) {
    $codigoU += substr_count($substring, $info);
}
```

This would increment `$codigoU` for each match in your `$info` string.  After counting the matches, you'd then perform your string replacement as you currently do.

Comment: Could you expand on the example? I can not understand it, thank you very much David.

Comment: @PlayerWet: Is there a specific part you don't understand?  This code simply adds the substring count to the variable for each substring you're replacing.

Comment: It's very strange the result @David, I've tried the loop and it does not increase the variable. Does the loop give two laps one for each element of the array?

The result of the variable is still 1000. Sorry for my clumsiness. :S

Comment: @PlayerWet: I can't really comment on code I can't see.  Perhaps you could update the question with the new code?

Comment: Today I tried it thoroughly and it works great. Thank you very much @David, you are a few cracks.